# Remote Database Connection String

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

Hi I am new to PHP and MySQL I have created an application on LAMP and uploaded on net4.com a website hosting company. They are using phpMyAdmin in order to connect to the database which I am able to successfully the problem arises when I try to connect to database using php and query the database. I am using the mysql_connect() function which I have been using successfully on my local machine to connect to the remote database i.e.

```
$link = mysql_connect("118.67.248.12",  "username", "password");
```

where "118.67.248.12" is the ip address of the server where my database resides, it throws the following error:

> "1045Access denied for user 'Technosaar'@'118.67.248.190' (using
>   password: YES)"

and if I use localhost" in place of "118.67.248.12" it throws the following error:

> "2002No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it."

I am already bugged up calling "net4" support guyz but the problem still persist Somebody please help me out, May Day May Day!

Comment: Please, if you're still in the process of learning PHP and MySQL, don't bother with learning about `mysql_*`, because it's being deprecated. Spend some time reading up on [`PDO` here](http://www.php.net/PDO) or, if needs must, [the `mysqli_*` connection](http://www.php.net/mysqli_connect), which offers an API which is very similar to the one of `mysql_*`

Answer (score 0):

The latter (localhost) isn't working I assume because the web server and database server aren't running on the same machine.

Are you certain that the password is set correctly on the server?  This looks like an authentication error to me.

Answer (score 0):

"1045 Access denied for user 'Technosaar'@'118.67.248.190' (using password: YES)" hints at missing access rights for the user `Technosaar` from your web server.
Login to phpmyadmin and enter the command

```
show grants;
```

or

```
show grants for '<myuser'@'<host>';
```

There should be a line like

> grant <privilege> on <mydatabase> to '<myuser>'@'<host>'

There you will see what access rights are configured for your user. If your webserver isn't listed, you must

```
grant all privileges on <mydatabase>.* to '<myuser>'@'<host>';
```

or whatever privileges you need for your database.

Insert the appropriate database name, user name and webserver host, of course.